# DynamoDB TransactWriteItems in AppSync resolver

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Recently AWS announced [DynamoDB Support for Transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-support-for-transactions/).
Is it possible to use DynamoDB [TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) API with AppSync Resolvers?

Comment: Hi, the DynamoDB resolvers in AWS AppSync do not support the transactional APIs at this time (Jan 2019). This is on our roadmap (no ETA to provide yet). You can use the Lambda resolvers to invoke transactional APIs in the meanwhile.

Comment: @RohanDeshpande +1 on this feature request.

Comment: Thanks. We’ve created a community site for AWS AppSync and I posted this request to https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/14. Please +1 there so we can prioritize the feature.